# Some PHP Function Flagged as Error in VSCode

Tags: php, codeigniter, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am a beginner and am developing a specific web system using PHP 8.2, Codeigniter 4 and XAMPP in VSCode. However, in my Controller, some PHP functions are marked as errors, such as `password_verify()`, `strpos()` etc. After I run it, the program runs fine. Where is the error? Is it in the VS Code program?

[image: the vs code screenshot]

The problem is:

> Expected type 'string'. Found 'array|null'.intelephense(1006)

For additional information, I am using Intelephense PHP extension 1.9.2. I also opened the code in PHPStorm and the error is not there. Thank you for any provided information.

When I uninstalled / disabled the Intelephense PHP, of course the error was not found. Whe I use PHP IntelliSense, it's did not even mark the function as an error. However, when Intelephense was re-enabled the PHP function was still marked as an error.

Comment: I'd say the error is in the plugin. It seems clear, especially since it disappeared when you uninstalled the plugin. Also have you actually tried to run the code? If it gets to that line and doesn't throw that error, then that also helps to prove it. But I think you've already answered your own question in the last paragraph, to be honest.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, my code is not pleasing to the eye when there are such error markers. Thanks for all the information. That's been resolved with Borjante's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `$request->getPost()` has a signature of `mixed|null`.
And `password_verify` a a signature of `string`.

You can cast it to string and the warning will dissapear.

```
$password = (string) $this->request->getPost('password')
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. The error marker that appeared has disappeared by adding `(string) $request->getPost()`. I have run the code and it still works.